# Polynomial equations in many variables have solutions (Lang 1952 paper)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, fields, class-field-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following result:

> Suppose $F$ is a function field in $k$ variables over an *algebraically closed* field. Let $f_1,...,f_r \in F[x_1,...,x_n]$ be polynomials without constant term of degrees $d_1,...,d_r$, respectively. Assume that $n>d_1^k+...+d_r^k$. Then $f_1,...,f_r$ have a non-trivial common zero. 
>   If $F$ is instead a function field in $k$ variables over a *finite* field, then these polynomials have a non-trivial common zero provided that $n>d_1^{k+1}+...+d_r^{k+1}$.

This is the Corollary on page 378 from the paper of [Lang 1952](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969785). The claim of the author is that this is a corollary of the Theorem 6 (that appears on the same page). However, to me, all that Theorem 6 seems to say is that $F$ is a $C_k$ field (for a definition see the same paper page 374) and I do not see this to be enough to obtain our conclusion. Theorem 4 of this paper (page 376) *does* show this statement but only when $f_i$ are *homogeneous* of degree $d_i$.

For the second part the author claims that this a corollary of the same theorem and of the following statement by Chevalley:

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field. Let $f_1,...,f_r \in \mathbb F[x_1,...,x_n]$ be polynomials without constant term of degrees $d_1,...,d_r$, respectively. Assume that $n>d_1+...+d_r$. Then $f_1,...,f_r$ have a non-trivial common zero.

but again I am struggling to put the ends together. I understand that I am supposed to understand this by myself, but I am new to the subject, and I feel a little bit lost.

I also realize that this seems like a double question, so probably it was inappropriate to post it in this way, but I believe that the reasoning for both parts should be very similar.

Comment: There are "normic forms" that allow you to generalize from a single polynomial to an $r$-tuple of polynomials.  Alternatively, you can set up the theory allowing tuples of polynomials, but the basic proofs then require more "bookkeeping" (that word has three consecutive double letters :)

Comment: Namely, one can apply theorem 4(the existence of normic forms of any degree is explained on p. 377)